# How can you check if a sublist is in a certain "window" of a larger list?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Given an arraylist and two start and end indexes, how can you check if a certain sub-ArrayList is present in the "window" i.e. between the indexes.

i.e.

```
private ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>;
private int start = 2, end = 6;
private ArrayList<Character> sublist = new ArrayList<Character>;

boolean present = isPresent();
```

How can I implement this isPresent() method efficiently? I will be using this method inside
a run-time encoding algorithm, to compress a text file (it's required I read it into an ArrayList first).

Comment: Is isPresent supposed to have start and end args?

Comment: in my class these are all instance variables... I will change that in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Collections.indexOfSubList(list.subList(start, end), subList) != -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
boolean iPresent(List l1, int start, int end, List l2) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (l2.size() > end - i) {
            break;
        }
        if (l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(0))) {
            return l1.subList(i, i + l2.size()).equals(l2);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that subList() returns a List backed by its parent list and does not create a new array, no need to worry about performance.

Comment: list2 is somewhere inside list1, they are not necessarily of the same length unfortunately...